# GitLab + VS Code : Host key verification failed. Error in the HTTP2 farming layer occur while cloning repo from GitLab using Visual Studio Code

Tags: gitlab, vscode, mac

Team,
I am facing following multiple issues with Visual Studio Code [Version - 1.68.1] while simple cloning remote repo to new GitLab account:

- Timeout Error : Unable to clone repository
- Fatal: unable to access 'myGitrepo.git'
- Error in the HTTP2 farming layer
- Host key verification failed
- Fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Environment :

- MacBook Pro [Apple M1 PRO]
- VS Code 1.68.1
- GitLab : Version control

Note - With brand new account I was trying to clone repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps which resolved my all above error and I could clone repo successful :

- Open Termial & paste : `git config --global user.name "YOUR_USERNAME"` and `git config --global user.email "<YOUR_EMAIL>"` This will set user name and email globally on your system for Git
- Open Termial and type `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "<your_email>"` [Hit Enter]
- Hit Enter key again to keep key in same directory. [Provide diff dir path ONLY for special purpose]
- Hit Enter for Passphrase and Confirm Passphrase. [**Important tweek** - Keep it blank and press enter key & **DO NOT ENTER ANY PASSPHRASE, It leads problems**]
- On success, you should see The key fingerprint created `tr -d '\n' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy` **for Mac**
- OR `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | clip` for Windows
- Chrome > Login GitLab > Profile > User Settings > SSH Keys > Add
- Paste copied public key & Click Add [**Recommended** : To use above cmd to **copy public key** instead of manually doing it]
- Key should get added successfully
- **Manual Check for GitLab Auth confirmation** : `ssh -T git@<your_GitLab_company_URL>` Expectation : Welcome message with <your_username>

References :
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#generate-an-ssh-key-pair